# router stopped working after an update

Tags: html, angularjs

I used to have the attached code working just fine, but then an update caused it to stop working. I was not able to make the adjustments so hopefully someone here has gone through it. The last block after the HTML is just smarty code to include the js file. The URL I am getting is: mySite.com/policies#!/#refund
which does not load anything. If I manually delete the second # to make it /policies#!/refund it does work.

This is the js file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'dialogs.main', 
'summernote', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate', 'fiestah.money', 'ui.ace', 
'ui.select', 'ngCart']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/main-app/policy/policy-reviews.tpl',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/reviews', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/main-app/policy/policy-reviews.tpl',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/currency', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/main-app/policy/policy-currency.tpl',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/refund', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/main-app/policy/policy-refund.tpl',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    });
```

});
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $http, $location, dialogs) {
    console.log("in ctrl");
});

This is the template:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div class="act-dash">
    <nav class="navbar-default content-header blue" role="navigation" style="position:relative;">
        <!-- We use the fluid option here to avoid overriding the fixed width of a normal container within the narrow content columns. -->
        <div id="admin-collapse" class="pad-left-fix" style="bottom:0px;">
            <div class="container"><h1>Terms and Policies</h1></div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="position:relative; bottom:0px">
                <li><a href="#reviews"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> </span>Comments and Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#currency"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"> </span>Currency Conversion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#refund"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"> </span>Refund Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
    <div class="content narrow-content margin-fix">
        <div class="row margin-fix margin-bottom-fix div-table" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="col-md-12 pad-left-fix pad-right-fix div-table-cell">
                <div style="text-align: left;">
                    <div id="main">
                        <!-- angular templating -->
                        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                        <div ng-view>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
{assign var="extra_js" scope="global" value="
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/angular-apps/policy.js\">
</script>
```

"}

Comment: this is not `ui-router`

Comment: What router is it then? @tanmay

Comment: can you try by adding `href="#!/reviews"` instead of `href="#reviews"`

Comment: It works! Can you explain why it is better than the answer here below? @VipinKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can Add Following line of code in your app.config, Just below
>   $routeProvider and see if it will work. Before run Please clear cache
>   and coockies on your browser.

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way without eliminating the prefix but it works! thank you!